# Помогите распарсить json на json

Tags: json, php

Прошу помощи у знающих. Мне надо для проекта сделать парс фотоблога на tumblr. Вот [ссылочка](http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/funclaw.tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4)

Нужны фотографии размеров По ширине 500. Незнаю как вытащить из массива. Помогите, если сможете. Спасибки.

Comment: $data = json_decode($jsondata);
потом сделай print_r($data) и увидите всю иерархию. возьмите нужный элемент и цикл

Answer (score 1):

Думаю доработать будет не сложно.

```
<?php
$data= file_get_contents('http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/funclaw.tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4');
$jsonData = json_decode($data);
$jsonDataPosts = $jsonData->response->posts;
foreach ($jsonDataPosts as $post){
    $photo = $post->photos[0]->alt_sizes[1]->url;
    echo $photo."\n";
}
```

получаем на выходе

```
http://25.media.tumblr.com/de7379ffe687e41a39631c084ad91a24/tumblr_mwwywzCfWe1s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://25.media.tumblr.com/8021344ce4de0735efa2eecc7f6cc006/tumblr_mwwyvx8rj61s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://25.media.tumblr.com/f758d645f9414a37ebf01aa182308082/tumblr_mwwyupbT0G1s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://25.media.tumblr.com/459ae529882b415779c89a735db84e4a/tumblr_mwwytiiNnw1s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://24.media.tumblr.com/7992b15a010fed9ade1584f0bb7eec12/tumblr_mwwysbIZDN1s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://25.media.tumblr.com/4ed239ab85515d2968e108de16b36b41/tumblr_mwwyrafKkt1s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://25.media.tumblr.com/080129fcfd806dcae6c6deffca4400fe/tumblr_mwwyq7khTH1s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://31.media.tumblr.com/d3e1e45a24cb82b22ebffca98906be89/tumblr_mwwyozj6Id1s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://25.media.tumblr.com/44b1aaf0a86ab89d2eb84e0c427e3d7c/tumblr_mwwyny8UA11s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://24.media.tumblr.com/5174112994a390bd095e892a5e8c7dda/tumblr_mwwympddQD1s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://25.media.tumblr.com/213e1c7274c55943f88516aa67dd67b6/tumblr_mwwylk50zi1s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://25.media.tumblr.com/940e7e9eee00005bfa703a832f904a39/tumblr_mwwykcgEqp1s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://24.media.tumblr.com/f543a8135b57defd9c9ef2499f74fd30/tumblr_mwlxb4gDNq1s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://24.media.tumblr.com/a37d8c17db24938b8bf37b2d290a7c15/tumblr_mwlxa4Nb1O1s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://31.media.tumblr.com/b39c9726f8468bce88d02230e270c95c/tumblr_mwlx97iPMB1s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://24.media.tumblr.com/265eab2dab46584cc0be1571c1a43a92/tumblr_mwlx83EhDk1s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://31.media.tumblr.com/55b8e26138a8a961e6dc9a79d6aacaf0/tumblr_mwlx73qLLR1s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://24.media.tumblr.com/c2b0f59765ea147d10da4a72cef84a5a/tumblr_mwlx62KZDi1s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://25.media.tumblr.com/273a8a1ad929989cf40f00b396cae025/tumblr_mwlx54zbxv1s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
http://31.media.tumblr.com/361cbaedd30293cbd9890e42097b9c53/tumblr_mwlx45hsXA1s8j3sqo1_500.jpg
```

Comment: если почитать документацию, то всегда не сложно, вот только как ТСов заставить читать :)

Answer (score -1):

json_decode по-умолчанию преобразовывает json в объект. Чтобы преобразовать в массив, сделай json_decode($jsondata, true);